# Crystal report only showing one record when a box is inserted

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I had created a Crystal Report with some fields like trinno, name, gender, age, etc.......

Then I am going to display the data in the report as usually, but, if we tried to draw the box and insert the columns in that box, it shows only one record. It doesn't show more then one record.

Answer (score 0):

1) What is 'the box'?

2) Are you placing the fields in the right report section?

3) Is your RecordSelectionFormula correct?